# dictionary comprehension with list iteration based on value dimensions

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Given

```
import numpy as np

t={'a':np.random.randint(0,9,[2,3]),'b':np.random.randint(0,9,[2,4])}
l=np.hstack([t.get(k) for k in t.keys()])
l=np.vstack((l, np.random.randint(0,9,[1,7])))
```

Is there a way to map list `l` in the above to a dictionary such that the keys map to the keys in dictionary `t` and values map to the modified list `l` aligned on columns, same as in `t`?

The following `for loop` works:

```
t2={}
s=0
e=0
for k in t.keys():
    e=s+t.get(k).shape[1]
    t2[k]=l[:,s:e]
    s=e
```

but I was wondering if there is a one liner dictionary comprehension equivalent to the above for loop?

Comment: I would say no, when iterating over a dictionary it is not sure that the order will be always the same, so in the code here, the information about the concatenation order of the arrays is lost... You could use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), but I think there is a better way to do this, could you give more detail about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @xdze2 it depends on your python version. As of [python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/) dicts are Officially ordered by the insertion order of their keys. It was already so in Cpython 3.6 but it was considered an [implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Your code depends on the order of the keys. Try to replace `for k in t.keys()` by `for k in ('b', 'a')` and you won't have the expected result. Even if the order of elements is guaranted since Python 3.7 (see comment) this might not be a good idea to rely on it.

You could use tuples:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0,9,[2,3])
b = np.random.randint(0,9,[2,4])

t = [('a', a), ('b', b)]
l = np.hstack([v for _, v in t])

c = np.random.randint(0,9,[1,7])
l = np.vstack((l, c))
```

To convert your code in a dict comprehension, you can compute the column indices:

```
import itertools
indices = list(itertools.accumulate((v.shape[1] for _, v in t)))
# [3, 7]
```

And then produce the arrays:

```
t2 = {k: l[:,s:s+v.shape[1]] for (k, v), s in zip(t, [0]+indices)}
```